# ITextSharp CSS Not Applying

Tags: html, css, xml, itext

i have implemented a html design in a page(default.aspx) with inline styles like , I would like to convert the same in to pdf file. So I have implemented the code with ITextSharp. But here the thing is css styles are not applying for pdf. alternatively i have implemented the same with XMLWorkerHelper. But its consuming heavy time to generate the pdf.Actually my requirement is to generate pdfs in billions in very less time.please give me a sample code to convert a template design to pdf very quickly.

Comment: Ehm, did you just say you need to generate billions of PDF files? Gee, how many computers do you have at your disposal?

Comment: Without seeings your actual code we can't help you.